# Visual Studio Code in Explorer's context menu

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-explorer

I want to be Visual Studio Code my default editor for all text-based file types in Windows. For Notepad++ there is an extension in the Windows Explorer to provide "Edit in Notepad++" for each file.
How can I achieve this for "Edit with Visual Studio Code"?
Do I have to "program" such extension on my own or are there any ready-to-use solutions available?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to this [blog post](http://thisdavej.com/right-click-on-windows-folder-and-open-with-visual-studio-code/) you can set this option during the installation process. If you want to add this option afterwards you either can follow the instructions of the rest of the post or (as recommended) reinstall vscode and then select that option during reinstalling.
When I faced the same issue, for me it was more comfortable to simply reinstall vscode.

Comment: re-installation was real fast and easy. No need to uninstall first, just get the installer and run it, choose the context menu options, and done.

Answer (score -8):

It is east !

step 1 -->
Right click the file you want to always open with VS code

example - if you want to always open .txt files in VS code then Right click on any .txt file that is in you system
[see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Evc2.png)

step 2 -->
click on 'open with'
[see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCLMV.png)

step 3 -->
click on 'choose another app'
[see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7Rvv.png)

step 4 -->
a new window will open, it will show all the applications on you system that are capable to open that file

click on VS code

and check the box at the bottom that says 'always use this app to open .txt files'
[see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPrGS.png)

and then click on open

THATS IT

NOW ON .txt FILES WILL BE OPENED IN VS CODE

.txt file extension is just an example, you can do this to any file example .py, .html, .pdf etc.

Comment: That was not the request. It was an option requested BESIDES the default application - an entry in the context menu like "Edit with VS Code" ... e.g. a .bat file I only want to edit open in VSC via context menu - not via default-app-double-click